# StarUML vs WhiteStarUML

Tags: uml, staruml

I have recently discovered that a new stable version of StarUML ([StarUML 2](http://staruml.io/)) has been released after the project being abandoned for a long time.

[WhiteStarUML](http://whitestaruml.sourceforge.net/) is a fork from the original StarUML project that provides modern continuation of the project using up-to-date development tools and libraries.

What are the pros and cons of both tools?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've used the both original StarUML(Unfortunately, it was abandoned so long time because it was developed as a commercial program first by a company in South Korea... but the company went bankrupt.) and StarUML2.0 I think WhiteStarUML is not very different from the original one.

StarUML2.0 is much better to see - anyway it is prettier. It's undeniable. :) and UI looks better. - But I felt it is a little bit uncomfortable when I draw some kind of diagrams... for me, especially sequence diagram. I guess it is because I'm familiar with the original StarUML.

What I want to say is, I think StarUML2.0 can be a little bit unfamiliar for users who have been using StarUML1 for long time. But If you want to show your diagram in your presentation, I recommend you to use StarUML2.0.

+) Now staruml 2.0 is charged. Personal license is $70. If you are a student, you need to pay only $49. The original starUML 5.0 is still for free.